# Keep track of number of times android application is opened

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sharedpreferences

I am making an android application in which I update SQLite database. I was wondering if I can track the number of times the application was opened.

Comment: How about using `SharedPereference` in `onCreate`?

Comment: Make SharedPref variable and increase every time on onCreate method.

Comment: You can use a conbination of sqlite and sharedPref.. so when you update the db.. store the open_app_counter in sharedPref.. and when finish update retrieve it and put it again in db_sqlite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by following approach.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("pref_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    int count = prefs.getInt("counter", 0);
    count+=1;
    editor.putInt("counter", count);
    editor.commit();

    Log.d("TAG","Counter : "+count);

}
```

Comment: brother i need u r help in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20088247/navigation-drawer-with-backword-compatibility-android/20088711#20088711 again please help me in this

Answer (score 2):

The the way you are going is correct. procedure just update the counter to the sqlite and access it from there.

SharedPereference is also possible but sqlite is better.

> follow this URL for reasons:
>   http://codeblow.com/questions/benefits-and-drawbacks-of-sqlite-and-shared-preferences/