# Implement Navigation Drawer in FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

My Activity extends FragmentActivity and implements the ActionBar.TabListener.

So now i want to implement the Navigation Drawer, so i change my layout in this:

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- The main content view -->

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

 <!-- The navigation drawer -->

<ListView
       android:id="@+id/drawer"
       android:layout_width="320dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_gravity="start"
       android:background="#F3F3F4"
       android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
       android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
       android:dividerHeight="0dp" ></ListView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And the extract of my code Java is:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    ab = getActionBar();
    ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ab.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);     






    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        ab.addTab(ab.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     * */
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            ab.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });


    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    rowID = extras.getString(Home.ROW_ID);
    Data = extras.getStringArrayList(Home.ROW_ID1);
    status = extras.getInt(Home.ROW_ID2);

    mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawer.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

    _initMenu();

    mDrawerToggle = new CustomActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer);
    mDrawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);


}
```

But i have error in my LogCat:

```
    01-14 15:26:03.671: E/AndroidRuntime(5806): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-14 15:26:03.671: E/AndroidRuntime(5806): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
01-14 15:26:03.671: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:242)
01-14 15:26:03.671: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3783)
01-14 15:26:03.671: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at felastech.websourcerequest.NsMenuAdapter.getView(NsMenuAdapter.java:94)
01-14 15:26:03.671: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2461)
01-14 15:26:03.671: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1775)
01-14 15:26:03.671: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:678)
01-14 15:26:03.671: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:739)
01-14 15:26:03.671: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1628)
01-14 15:26:03.671: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2296)
01-14 15:26:03.671: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
01-14 15:26:03.671: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
01-14 15:26:03.671: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:702)
01-14 15:26:03.671: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
01-14 15:26:03.671: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
01-14 15:26:03.671: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
01-14 15:26:03.671: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
01-14 15:26:03.671: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
01-14 15:26:03.671: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
01-14 15:26:03.671: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
01-14 15:26:03.671: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
01-14 15:26:03.671: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
01-14 15:26:03.671: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
01-14 15:26:03.671: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
01-14 15:26:03.671: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
01-14 15:26:03.671: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
01-14 15:26:03.671: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1992)
01-14 15:26:03.671: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1813)
01-14 15:26:03.671: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1112)
01-14 15:26:03.671: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4472)
01-14 15:26:03.671: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
01-14 15:26:03.671: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
01-14 15:26:03.671: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
01-14 15:26:03.671: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
01-14 15:26:03.671: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-14 15:26:03.671: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-14 15:26:03.671: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-14 15:26:03.671: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
01-14 15:26:03.671: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-14 15:26:03.671: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-14 15:26:03.671: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
01-14 15:26:03.671: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
01-14 15:26:03.671: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and this is the code of error in LogCat, in NsMenuAdapter Class:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            NsMenuItemModel item = getItem(position);
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            View view = convertView;

            if (view == null) {
                    int layout = R.layout.ns_menu_row_counter;
                    if (item.isHeader)
                            layout = R.layout.ns_menu_row_header;

                    view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(layout, null);

                    TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.menurow_title);
                    ImageView image1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.menurow_icon);
                    TextView textcounter1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.menurow_counter);
                    view.setTag(new ViewHolder(text1, image1,textcounter1));
            }

            if (holder == null && view != null) {
                    Object tag = view.getTag();
                    if (tag instanceof ViewHolder) {
                            holder = (ViewHolder) tag;
                    }
            }


        if(item != null && holder != null)
        {
                if (holder.textHolder != null)
                            holder.textHolder.setText(item.title);

                if (holder.textCounterHolder != null){
                        if (item.counter > 0){
                                holder.textCounterHolder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                holder.textCounterHolder.setText(""+item.counter);
                        }else{
                                holder.textCounterHolder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                    }

            if (holder.imageHolder != null) {
                            if (item.iconRes > 0) {
                                    holder.imageHolder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    holder.imageHolder.setImageResource(item.iconRes);
                            } else {
                                    holder.imageHolder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                    }
        }

        return view;                
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20088247/navigation-drawer-with-backword-compatibility-android/20088711#20088711. check this

Comment: i can't use with  FragmentActivity ?

Answer (score 1):

It says Resource Not Found, From that i guess either of the TextView is unable to find resource form the inflated layout.
Check for layout if you have those ids in layout.

Comment: this is not the problem