# DrawerItemClickListener cannot be resolved to a type - Android app

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I already checked around if my issue has been solved but I can't find it out.

I want to do a drawer menu, using DrawerItemClickListener.

I'm using API 19 to Android 4.4.2
Here's my import :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Toast;
```

It's kinda weird because I downloaded a sample from android developers website which work well with Drawer.
At first I thougth I didn't have the good library but I replaced mine with my sample, nothing change!

I don't know how to solve that problem...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

final String TEST = "user_password";
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;
private String[] mPlanetTitles;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) RelativeLayout.inflate(this, R.layout.fragment_main, null);
    setContentView(layout);
    TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    text.setText("Calculez votre IMC !");

    Button b = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final TextView text2 = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    final EditText poids = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final EditText taille = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    b.setText("Calculez");
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String rawSize = taille.getText().toString();

            Float p = Float.parseFloat(poids.getText().toString());
            if (rawSize.indexOf(',') == -1 && rawSize.indexOf('.') == -1 && rawSize.length() == 3)
            {
                StringBuilder tmp = new StringBuilder();
                tmp.append(rawSize.charAt(0));
                tmp.append('.');
                tmp.append(rawSize.charAt(1));
                tmp.append(rawSize.charAt(2));
                rawSize = tmp.toString();
            }

            if (rawSize.indexOf(',') != -1)
                rawSize = rawSize.replace(',', '.');

            Float t = Float.parseFloat(rawSize);
            int res = (int) (p / Math.pow(t, 2));
            text2.setText("Votre IMC est de : "+res);
        }
    });

    final Button loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(TEST, poids.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
    //mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                  /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
            ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}
```

I have a relative layout instead of a frame one (like the sample I downloaded) but I don't thing it is the problem.

Comment: Does your project includes android-support-v4 library?

Comment: I think so. If I go on eclipse in "android private library", there is android-support-v4.

Comment: Do you have a class called `DrawerItemCLickListener`

Comment: What if you change your XML? By elimination, as you stated, the XML seems to be the only difference.

Comment: @shkschneider xml has nothing to do with op's problem. Op does not seem to have a class by name `DrawerItemCLickListener`

Comment: @user3561383 can you post the full code and skip the import statements for now

Comment: @Raghunandan you're right. The inner private class DrawerItemClickListener from the Google example seems missing.

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/imc here's my code.

@Raghunandan > I don't have such class.

I will edit my first post with complete code.

Comment: @user3561383 post it here. don't link to external sites. the links can be dead in the future and your question becomes uselsess without code

Comment: @user3561383 and i am not downlaoding your file and code

Comment: I updated my first post !

I don't want you to code, I just looking for the easiest way you can understand my problem.

Comment: @user3561383 clear missing a class `DrawerItemClickListener`. Follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20088247/navigation-drawer-with-backword-compatibility-android/20088711#20088711. Note this is using support library for backward compatibility but conceptually same

Comment: I don't know why I should use ActionBarActivity instead of Activity when my downloaded sample is working...

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem and found a solution. I created a private `DrawerItemClickListener`

```
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position,long id) {

        // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle("......");

        String text= "menu click... should be implemented";
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

    }
}
```