# Why DrawerLayout and ActionBar not working on Tablets?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, drawerlayout

I'm develop some app with sliding menu.
when i try to run this on my galaxy 4s(api 18+ 4.3.3) its work fine!
but when i run this on xperia arc (api 8 ver 2.3.4) the app crash.
i know its dependent on Support library and i use :
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;

and i need to use :

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
```

so i added to my project the support library and connect the support library to him.

but i dont know how to handle the support and what i need to chage on my code:

my java code (v4){

```
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnLongClickListener , OnTouchListener , OnItemClickListener{
/////////////////
ArrayList<ItemInSetting > listSetting = new ArrayList<ItemInSetting>();
CustomAdapterSetting adapterSetting;
DrawerLayout drawer;
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
//////////////////

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    settingItems();
     }

public void settingItems(){

    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, R.drawable.ic_drawer, 0, 0){

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle("menu");

            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle("app title");
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

    };drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);

    listSetting.add(new ItemInSetting("ist1", R.drawable.calende_bigg));
    listSetting.add(new ItemInSetting("ist2", R.drawable.calende_bigg));
    listSetting.add(new ItemInSetting("ist3", R.drawable.calende_bigg));
    listSetting.add(new ItemInSetting("ist4", R.drawable.calende_bigg));

    lvSetting = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listSetting);
    lvSetting.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    adapterSetting = new CustomAdapterSetting(listSetting, this);
    lvSetting.setAdapter(adapterSetting);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    date = new Date();
    switch (position) {

    case 0:
        Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this,ListOfHours.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        break;      
    case 1:
        getSetting();

        if(sickIsOn){
            cancelingFreeday(false);
        }else{
            addingManualMenu();
        }

        break;      
    case 2:
        changingSetting(" ");
        break;
    case 3:

        sendContact();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    drawer.closeDrawers();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title

    if (toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
      // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.

    toggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls

    toggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

my xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/new_back"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listSetting"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" >
        </ListView>
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bib.workclock"
    android:versionCode="52"
    android:versionName="3.0.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_new3"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
   <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" 
   android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

        <activity
            android:name="com.bibas.workclock.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="ListOfHours"   ></activity>

        <activity android:name="HelpPage"></activity>

        <activity android:name="info" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

    </application>
   </manifest>
```

this the locat error when i try to run on xperia :

```
05-04 01:59:05.058: E/AndroidRuntime(15484): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-04 01:59:05.058: E/AndroidRuntime(15484): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.bba.workclock.MainActivity.getActionBar
05-04 01:59:05.058: E/AndroidRuntime(15484):    at com.bba.workclock.MainActivity.settingItems(MainActivity.java:1657)
05-04 01:59:05.058: E/AndroidRuntime(15484):    at com.bba.workclock.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:124)
05-04 01:59:05.058: E/AndroidRuntime(15484):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-04 01:59:05.058: E/AndroidRuntime(15484):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
05-04 01:59:05.058: E/AndroidRuntime(15484):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
05-04 01:59:05.058: E/AndroidRuntime(15484):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
05-04 01:59:05.058: E/AndroidRuntime(15484):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
05-04 01:59:05.058: E/AndroidRuntime(15484):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-04 01:59:05.058: E/AndroidRuntime(15484):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-04 01:59:05.058: E/AndroidRuntime(15484):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
05-04 01:59:05.058: E/AndroidRuntime(15484):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-04 01:59:05.058: E/AndroidRuntime(15484):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-04 01:59:05.058: E/AndroidRuntime(15484):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
05-04 01:59:05.058: E/AndroidRuntime(15484):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
05-04 01:59:05.058: E/AndroidRuntime(15484):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**here is project like mine:
http://speedy.sh/UKsrV/SlidingMenu.zip
if any one can fix that code and give it to me back i appreciate alot**

How can i fix this?!! 
please help me :(((

**I FIX THAT PROBLEM BUT KNOW ON MY TABLET IT'S CRASH .**

here the locat error:

```
05-11 23:10:22.127: E/AndroidRuntime(31723): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-11 23:10:22.127: E/AndroidRuntime(31723): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Child android.widget.FrameLayout@41f91e40 at index 0 does not have a valid layout_gravity - must be Gravity.LEFT, Gravity.RIGHT or Gravity.NO_GRAVITY
05-11 23:10:22.127: E/AndroidRuntime(31723):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:721)
05-11 23:10:22.127: E/AndroidRuntime(31723):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15479)
05-11 23:10:22.127: E/AndroidRuntime(31723):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4826)
05-11 23:10:22.127: E/AndroidRuntime(31723):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
05-11 23:10:22.127: E/AndroidRuntime(31723):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15479)
05-11 23:10:22.127: E/AndroidRuntime(31723):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
05-11 23:10:22.127: E/AndroidRuntime(31723):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
05-11 23:10:22.127: E/AndroidRuntime(31723):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15479)
05-11 23:10:22.127: E/AndroidRuntime(31723):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4826)
05-11 23:10:22.127: E/AndroidRuntime(31723):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
05-11 23:10:22.127: E/AndroidRuntime(31723):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2359)
05-11 23:10:22.127: E/AndroidRuntime(31723):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15479)
05-11 23:10:22.127: E/AndroidRuntime(31723):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1968)
05-11 23:10:22.127: E/AndroidRuntime(31723):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1214)
05-11 23:10:22.127: E/AndroidRuntime(31723):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1387)
05-11 23:10:22.127: E/AndroidRuntime(31723):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
05-11 23:10:22.127: E/AndroidRuntime(31723):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4464)
05-11 23:10:22.127: E/AndroidRuntime(31723):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
05-11 23:10:22.127: E/AndroidRuntime(31723):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
05-11 23:10:22.127: E/AndroidRuntime(31723):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
05-11 23:10:22.127: E/AndroidRuntime(31723):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
05-11 23:10:22.127: E/AndroidRuntime(31723):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-11 23:10:22.127: E/AndroidRuntime(31723):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-11 23:10:22.127: E/AndroidRuntime(31723):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-11 23:10:22.127: E/AndroidRuntime(31723):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
05-11 23:10:22.127: E/AndroidRuntime(31723):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-11 23:10:22.127: E/AndroidRuntime(31723):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-11 23:10:22.127: E/AndroidRuntime(31723):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
05-11 23:10:22.127: E/AndroidRuntime(31723):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
05-11 23:10:22.127: E/AndroidRuntime(31723):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: No body is going to fix your code and post it back. I have posted what needs to be done correction.

Comment: but ist still not working :( i have alot of users on this app 10,000+ and its importent to me to gives them all support they need

Comment: i have posted a link with complete example. rest is upto you to correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActionBar` is available from api level 11. To support below api level 11 you need to use AppCompat from the support library. Reference `AppCompat` in your android project.

You need to extend `ActionBarActivity`. Use theme derived from `Theme.AppCompat` in manifest and use `getSupportActionBar()`.

Complete example @

[Navigation Drawer with backword compatibility android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20088247/navigation-drawer-with-backword-compatibility-android/20088711#20088711)

Check **Adding libraries with resources**

https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

And read

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Comment: oops ! but now i have a new problem on my tablet it doesn't work :/

Comment: @ANDROBIB new problem new question. You need to design layouts fro tablets

Comment: @ANDROBIB also its self explanatory `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Child android.widget.FrameLayout@41f91e40 at index 0 does not have a valid layout_gravity - must be Gravity.LEFT, Gravity.RIGHT or Gravity.NO_GRAVITY`